# Keyboard wont allow typing charecters fast

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-accelerators

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 last day, but keyboard is annoying me . it doesn't allow two same character type after each other, like "allow", first 'l' is alright but for typing second 'l' i have to wait a sec and press again.

its stupid, why they make it like this ?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure, that you disabled either **Sticky** or **Slow Keys** under "Accessibility menu" and it should work!! Please let us know if that solved your problem!

[image]

Comment: You are very welcome PayamB!!

Answer (score 3):

Please be sure you don't have accessibility features enabled.

There's a specific option for this.

Comment: After my comment i saw, that you already posted the right answer, so +1 up for you and sorry!!